# Different WAN and external IP address unable to port forward due to this

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I was trying to port forward but the ports remained closed every time. Then I noticed that the WAN IP (address on router page) and the external IP are different. The local IP is 192.168.x.x, WAN IP is in the 10.179.x.x range and the external IP is in the 103.x.x.x range. When I opened the routing table in the router page I found another IP in the 103.x.x.x range which when opened in the browser opened to a RouterOS page. Also, the default gateway and IP address of the WAN connection is the same and subnet mask is 255.255.255.255

The network topology I understand is like My router > ISP switch > Wireless Device which connects to the external network. Now my questions are:
1. How do I forward my ports and can I do it without ISP help?
2. Do switches have management pages like routers? If yes then
3. How do I access the switch from behind my router to setup port forwarding?

Comment: do you mean port forward as in https://portforward.com/   or port forwarding as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding  ? What ports are you using? What router do you have?  Access to an ISP switch on their side, highly unlikely.

Comment: yeah portforward.com, i am trying to host a game and a teamspeak server, it isnt exactly an ISP switch it is used in the building to save IP addresses like all the users in the building will have the same external IP address. This saves addresses for the ISP to allocate to other users.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your ISP should be drawn and quartered. What you have described sounds like a network where the ISP is running NAT (but not Carrier Grade NAT as they have not used the CGN IP range.)  Further, other devices on the network are open to being hacked by others on the network.

If, as it seems, your ISP is using NAT, you would need there help to set up port forwarding.